# ssh as super user

Tags: ssh, sudo, chmod

I did the following mistake on a remote server :

```
# sudo chmod 700 /
```

Now no user but root can do anything. I can't even ssh as a normal user anymore, since I don't have permission to access bash.

My question is the following: in the event that I can't log in as root, is there a way I can *directly* ssh to my server with super-user rights?

Comment: You can add your user to sudoers. That should work..

Comment: Oops I did not see your comment -- thanks, but unfortunately even though my account is among the sudoers, I cannot ssh regularly ("/bin/bash: Permission denied" is the error I obtain).

Comment: Ahh ok, figured that would be worth trying out. But I think that drs answer is the only way to log in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless it's been explicitly disabled, you can `ssh` using your root user:

```
ssh root@hostname.com
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- I'm investigating that now but, in the event that it's disabled, is there a way one can *directly* ssh as a regular user with super-user rights ?

Comment: @user27834 No (for security reasons)